# Display query results in calendar format

Tags: sql, oracle, calendar

I have four tables CUSTOMERS, PRODUCTS, CALENDAR, ORDERS with data as -

1) CUSTOMERS [CUST is PK]

```
CUST
----
ABC Inc
XYZ Corporation
```

2) PRODUCTS [PID is PK]

```
PID     PRODUCT
---     -------
101     Chair
102     Table
103     Sofa
104     Cot
```

3) CALENDAR [DATE is PK] - Simple calendar table to store dates and days

```
DATE        DAY
----        ---
2015-01-01  THU
2015-01-02  FRI
....
2015-06-30  TUE
```

4) ORDERS [OID is PK] - To store order information

```
OID     CUST     DATE        PID     QUANTITY
---     ----     ----        ---     --------
1       ABC Inc  2015-02-17  101     2
2       ABC Inc  2015-02-17  102     5
3       ABC Inc  2015-02-18  102     1
4       ABC Inc  2015-02-18  103     8
5       ABC Inc  2015-02-18  104     6
```

Please help me to fetch order details using SQL/PLSQL for ABC Inc customer that should display PRODUCT, and QUANTITY in a calendar format (5 workdays in a week) as-

```
PRODUCT     2015-02-16  2015-02-17  2015-02-18  2015-02-19  2015-02-20
-------     ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
Chair       (null)      2           (null)      (null)      (null)
Table       (null)      5           1           (null)      (null)
Sofa        (null)      (null)      8           (null)      (null)
Cot         (null)      (null)      6           (null)      (null)
```

All the products should be displayed in 1st column. The beginning and ending work dates of the week should be decided by sysdate.

Comment: look like `pivot` in action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `PIVOT` :

```
   WITH pvt AS (
           SELECT p.product, o.quantity, o.date
           FROM   Orders o
           JOIN Products p on o.pid=p.pid
           )
   SELECT *
   FROM   pvt
   PIVOT (
          quantity                    
          FOR date
          IN  ('2015-02-16','2015-02-17','2015-02-18', '2015-02-19','2015-02-20')   
         );
```

Comment: `'2015-02-16'` is not a DATE, it is a string.

Comment: `Yes of course`, as user have not mentioned so I'm not sure what is the datatype of date field (it may be varchar!!, but propabebly it's date if yes then user needs to cast it i.e: by using `to_date`

Comment: OP has clearly mentioned it is a **DATE** data column. *`CALENDAR [DATE is PK] - Simple calendar table to store dates and days`*

Comment: No, sorry not crearly, the date he/she mentioned is `name of column` not the `datatype` just look at he/she 's same description for other tables.

Comment: however thanks for your comments, the comments are really noticeable and I should consider standards which "datatype for a date column is `date`", and your comments completes the answer, but I don't like revising and editing answer too much so I maybe not edit it because I'm afraid about editing too much.

Comment: Oh wow that works really fine and does half of my job, but I don't want to write any dates I want to search for in the pivot_in_clause, because  they are beginning(SUN) and ending(SAT) dates of the week which are dynamic and depend on the sysdate.
So is there a way to write a SELECT in the pivot_in_clause? I tried it myself but it always gives me an ORA-00936: "missing expression" error and I don't know why.